# Python: creating and copying numpy arrays in Numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am using Numba a lot to speed up many loops which cannot be vectorised and would otherwise be very slow.
My questions are:

1. Can a Numba function create numpy arrays? I haven't found a way: functions like np.zeros don't work in Numba.
   What I do now is create empty arrays (initialised with zeros or
   NaNs) outside of Numba and passing them to my Numba function, which
   then fills them based on the calculation of my loop.

   2. Can Numba
      do a deep copy of a numpy array? I often have to work on many arrays
      of the same size. Numba can run `array2 = array1` , but array2
      becomes a reference to array1 (changing one changes the other).
   3. When I have non-Numba functions with many inputs and many outputs, I
      like to create classes with no methods for inputs and outputs. This
      way I can run something like:

   myinput.input_1= foo1

   myinput.input_2 = foo2

   myoutput = myfunction(myinput)

which is convenient when I have 20 inputs and 20 outputs. Can Numba support anything like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numba is under active development, so the answer to your question depends on the version. In Numba >0.19, you gain the ability to create numpy arrays in `nopython` mode. All supported numpy constructs are listed at:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.20.0/reference/numpysupported.html

`arr.copy()` is also supported in `nopython` mode at least in 0.20 (where I checked).

In terms of passing in an object containing arrays as attributes, you can do this in object mode `nopython=False`, but it won't work in `nopython` mode. You'll have to then check what sort of speed-ups you get. Numba may be able to do some subsequent loop-lifting in that case.

My recommendation is, if possible, to stay up-to-date with the Numba releases. They are adding a lot of features and in my experience, fixing a lot of bugs as well.

Comment: Can I pass a dataframe to Numba in nopython mode, so that Numba can then access dataframe.field1, dataframe.field2, etc? I would normally test this myself, but I don't have admin rights on my machine: installing a new version, tetsing it, and maybe rolling back to the previous one if anything is incompatible with my previous code is not the most straightforward process. Thanks!

Comment: Numba, I'm pretty sure doesn't natively handle Pandas DataFrames in nopython mode. My recommendation vis-a-vis updating Numba is (if possible), use the Anaconda Python Distribution (https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), it's free and does not require admin privileges to install and will allow you to manage package versions via conda. Most people I know working in data science/scientific computing use it, and I highly recommend it.

Comment: That's the one I'm using, but admin rights are still needed to access and download the remote repositories. It's to do more with the network setup than with my specific PC